# How make database connection using aura sql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql. And i want to connect with database using aura sql.

```
<?php
$connection_factory = include '/Aura/scripts/instance.php';
$connection = $connection_factory->newInstance(

    // adapter name
    'mysql',

    // DSN elements for PDO; this can also be
    // an array of key-value pairs
    'host=localhost;dbname=db_aura',

    // username for the connection
    'root',

    // password for the connection
    ''
);

$result = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM tbl_test');
?>
```

The above code shows the error

**Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\1\Aura\src\Aura\Sql\Connection\AbstractConnection.php on line 65**

Comment: Are you getting errors? Why are you asking if it's correct, have you not tried it?

Comment: SO is not a website to proof read your code. People come here to get answers to "real" (as in code) problems!

Comment: i tried but shows error? How can i make correct that i meant, sorry.

Comment: @Luceos : Help if you know it.I know SO is for what.

Comment: @deepus; also add the errors to you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it...

The code given above in my question is correct. Error occured due the version of my php i used. PHP version above 5.4 only support this. Now am using php 5.4.12 and aura sql is able to connect with mysql and working well.. Thanks.